# Last firebase notification action overrides the older ones in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the problem: I am displaying notifications just fine, if I send 3 notifications I am able to see all 3 of them. However, regardless of which notification I hit or if I open the app. It will always do the action of the last notification, and it discards the older wants.

What I want it to do is on it/open app, start with the newest one and proceed to the older ones.

Do I have to deal with this using just logic? or is there a method like using pending intents that I could use?

I do not necessarily need the code to fix this, just an explanation on how to approach this could do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Check if the `requestCode` which you are passing via `NOTIFICATION` is different for each `PendingIntent` or not.

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` updates `PendingIntent` with the new `Intent` for a given `requestCode`.

I think, whats happening in your case is, you are passing same value for `requestCode` in `PendingIntent.getActivity()` method, which means you are giving same id to all the 3 `Intents`, and since you have specified a flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, android will update `Intent` for all the Pending Intents with last provided Intent.

Try to specify different `requestCode` for different `PendingIntent`s. I think this should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! Let me see if I understand, the way to fix it would be to change where I am calling the function? the Intent that I am passing? or would it be to change the function itself?

Comment: In this line, `PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
` You need to make sure that `NOTIFICATION` value is different for different notifications.

Comment: thank you soo much you saved my life @dfabiano and also thanks to  Kalpesh Patel for asking this question